# Different kinds of do's

Tags: syntax, english, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

At first I thought that there was only such a thing as lexical do and periphrastic, but recently I stumbled upon something else (unfortunately I do not recall what it was called). Whatever be the case, it seems that *do* can be used for quite a lot of grammatical things (*do*-support being one). Could someone give some of these roles *do* can play?

Comment: Good question. There are indeed several different functions for the English auxiliary verb _do,_ just as there are for all English auxiliary verbs.

Comment: I created some new tags for this question. I feel "do" has enough different meanings, usages, and subtleties to warrant a tag all its own but this site isn't just for English. I also think the "syntax" tag is a better one for this question than the "grammar" tag so I've changed that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In English, certainly the most common use of *do* is *Do*-Support.
DS is invoked whenever a construction requiring an auxiliary verb (like Question or Negative):

- S: *Bill is coming today*  Ques: *Is Bill coming today?*  Neg: *Bill isn't coming today.*

gets applied to a verb chain without an auxiliary verb in it already; i.e, a bare main verb:

- S: *Bill came today*  Ques: ***Did*** Bill come today?  Neg: *Bill **didn't** come today.*

As I used to tell my students, if you don't have an auxiliary verb,
you have to go out and get one, and the one that you get is ***do***.

*Do*-Support applies to any verb that's not an auxiliary, no matter what it means.

This is not true, however, of a different kind of *do*, called "Action *do*" or `Act` for short.
(See John R. Ross, 1972. "Act", in Davidson & Harman, *Semantics of Natural Languages* )
This is the *do* that is the pro-verb for any **active** verb (just like a pronoun is for nouns),
but which doesn't work with **stative** verbs like *own*.

This distinguishes `Act` *do* from *Do*-Support *do*:

- *Bill raked the yard, didn't he?* (*Do*-Support *do*, active verb)
- *Bill use to own that house, didn't he?* (*Do*-Support *do*, stative verb)
- *Raking the yard was not pleasant for Bill, but he did it.* (`Act` *do*, active verb)
- **Owning the house was not pleasant for Bill, but he did it.* (`Act` *do*, stative verb - therefore ungrammatical, whence the asterisk)

Plus any number of other uses for *do* (*Why don't we do it in the road?* - both `do`'s, no waiting)

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd just like to add that *do* can be inserted to contrastively focus the polarity of an assertion, e.g. *A: John didn't go to shops. B: That's wrong. John DID go to the shops*". Maybe one could analyse this as another example of *do*-support - an auxiliary must be present to host the contrastive stress, and so *do* is inserted.

Comment: Yes, emphatic _do_ is another. I was happy to turn off the tap, though, since it wasn't clear which phenomenon the OQ was referring to.

Comment: Also _do_ can be used as a universal substitution for any verb: Q: Who knows Tom? A: I do.

Comment: @YellowSky: That's _Do_-Support. Q: _Is Tom here?_ A: _*He does._

Comment: @YellowSky Like jlawler says, this is an example of *do*-support under VP-Ellipsis. Since an overt auxiliary must be present to license VP-ellipsis, *do* is inserted. If an overt aux is present, *do* is unnecessary, e.g. *Q: Who would like to know Tom? A: I would* (but not *i do*).

Comment: A good point, friends. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Great answer (and comments). Thank you. Could you by any chance work the terms "emphatic" and "periphrastic" in there? Because - yet again - terminology seems to confuse me.

Comment: Emphatic do has already been mentioned by P Elliott; and they're all periphrastic since they're all auxiliary verbs. "Periphrastic" is not a name, but a description; it means "paraphrased with auxiliaries", so the entire English verb phrase can be called periphrastic. It's not a useful term here. If you've come across a construction some folks call "periphrastic _do_", trot out an example and we'll identify it.

Comment: @BramVanroy Based on this article: http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cpercy/courses/6361Aho.htm it looks like *periphrastic do* is used to refer to the *do* found in *do*-support, i.e. Subj-Aux inversion, negation, VP ellipsis, and arguably emphatic do. Generally, *Periphrastic do* refers to cases where *do* seems to be semantically vacuous, having a purely functional role in the sentence,

Comment: Which is why I prefer to call it "_Do_-Support _do_"; I'm a category Splitter by inclination and never trust official category Lumps.